# Searching functions using grep over multiple loaded packages in R

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

Lets say I have package `base`, `dplyr`, `data.table`, `tidyr` etc. loaded using `sapply()`.

```
 sapply(c("dplyr","data.table","tidyr"),library,character.only=TRUE)
```

So to check the list of functions in a particular package I do

```
 ls("package:data.table")
```

Now if I want to search for functions inside `dplyr` starting with `is.` pattern I do

```
 grep("is\\.",ls("package:dplyr"),value=TRUE)
 # [1] "is.grouped_df" "is.ident"      "is.sql"        "is.src"       
 # [5] "is.tbl"
```

My Goal is to search for all the functions starting with `is.` or `as.` or any other pattern in multiple packages simultaneously. The code I think would be lengthy i.e. below I have combined list of `dplyr` and `base` functions and then added grep pattern. How to do it for many loaded packages?

```
 grep("is\\.",c(ls("package:dplyr"),ls("package:base")),value=T)
```

Function `search()` would give me list of loaded packages. But how to gather all the functions of loaded packages, so that I can later `grep` on it.

For a single package, list of functions can be obtained by

```
 ls("package:package_name")
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a list of all packages which are loaded, use:

```
x <- grep('package:',search(),value=TRUE)  # Comment below by danielson
# e.g. ("package:base", "package:data.table")

sapply(x, function(x) {
    paste0(x, ":", grep("is\\.", ls(x),value=TRUE))
})
```

**Output:**

```
$`package:base`
 [1] "package:base:is.array"              "package:base:is.atomic"
 [3] "package:base:is.call"               "package:base:is.character"
 [5] "package:base:is.complex"            "package:base:is.data.frame"
 [7] "package:base:is.double"             "package:base:is.element"
 ...

$`package:data.table`
[1] "package:data.table:is.data.table"
```

Comment: I like the answer. But, lets say there are 100 packages loaded using `library`. Now to see the loaded packages list, I say `search()` on console. I can not sit and write 100 of them inside `c()` So I would need an answer where x is larger and gets combined very easily.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian I agree that you need a way to get a list of the installed packages.  For this, use `installed.packages()[,1]`.  With regard to combining the results, I think the output I gave is reasonable.  Typically, you always have to read through some documentation to choose a function or method, and your use case isn't any different AFAIK.

Comment: We can also do like `x <- search()[-1]` and then slight changes inside `sapply()`. Almost solved my problem.

Comment: Not installed packages but loaded ones.

Comment: `x <- grep('package:',search(),value=TRUE)` in the code above?

Comment: @danielson Wow!! your command would remove the `.GlobalEnv` and `Autoloads` from the search list. Thanks!!

Comment: TIm and danielson..Thank you both for getting this output achieved together.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Even Amazing!! Now I'll have different versions!

Comment: Why not drop `grep` and use the `pattern` arg in `ls()`?  `ls("package:base", pattern = "is\\.")`

Comment: @RichScriven Wow, this too works inside `sapply()` Just did that for all loaded packages. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. So here are Answers in 3 Versions to the question I posted with all the help here

**Note: The priority was to search for a pattern over multiple loaded packages, you can search some other pattern instead of "is."**

**VERSION 1**

```
 ## Get list of loaded packages into X 

 X <- grep('package:',search(),value=TRUE)  # Comment by danielson

 # Use grep to find functions with is. pattern over multiple loaded packages inside X

 sapply(X, function(X) {
 paste0(X, ":", grep("is\\.", ls(X),value=TRUE))
 })
```

**VERSION 2**

```
 ## Get list of loaded packages into X 

 X <- .packages()    # Comment by docendo discimus

 # Use grep to find functions with is. pattern over multiple loaded packages inside X

 sapply(X, function(X) {
 paste0(X, ":", grep("is\\.", ls(paste0("package:",X)),value=TRUE))
 })
```

**VERSION 3  - Without grep() function**

```
 ## Get list of loaded packages into X 

 X <- .packages()

 # find functions using `ls()` with is. pattern over multiple loaded packages inside X
 # Suggested by Rich Scriven Over Comments

 sapply(X, function(X) { 
 paste0(X,":",ls(paste0("package:",X), pattern = "is\\."))
 })
```