# R: Searching package code in CRAN or installed locally

Tags: r, search, codebase

Suppose I wish to find instances of the use of one or more functions in the code of `base` or submitted packages, for purpose of better understanding idiomatic use of those functions. That is to say, I want to do a code search for the places where a function is used, not a search for places where that function is defined. So I would want to include e.g., unexported functions.

Ideally I would like to do RegEx matching so as to find functions with similar names that might serve a parallel function. I would also like to be able to restrict the output based on R's logical tests of output type, to find, e.g., only functions, or some finer subdivisions, such as `is.primitive()` or `is.closure()`, or  (from `rlang`) `is_primitive_eager()` or `is_primitive_lazy()`.

I note that some of the kinds of search I am asking about exist for package documentation in the `sos` package. Also, I know that grep searches can be done on the names of exported functions of loaded  packages, as here: [Searching functions using grep over multiple loaded packages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483717/searching-functions-using-grep-over-multiple-loaded-packages-in-r), and Jim Hester's `lookup` package finds function definitions in CRAN packages even if they are not installed. See also Ben Bolker's answer, here: [Name of a package for a given function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553755/name-of-a-package-for-a-given-function-in-r/10553795#10553795) But none of these methods will search for function usage as opposed to function definition.

Comment: Couldn't you just fork/download base and do a simple regex over the source files?